# CheckBox does not toggle on in PDF view in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, checkbox

When I convert a layout to PDF, `Name` shows the text even in PDF but the `CheckBox` does not toggle on in PDF.

I try to put the `CheckBox` toggle on in XML layout and when I convert to PDF, the `CheckBox` shows correctly but programmatically does not work.

```
TextView tvName = content.findViewById(R.id.txtNameInsert);
CheckBox chM = content.findViewById(R.id.checkMinsert);

tvName.setText(Name.getText());
chM.toggle();

content.draw(page.getCanvas());
document.finishPage(page);

String targetPdf = "/sdcard/pdffromlayout.pdf";
File filePath;
filePath = new File(targetPdf);
try {
    document.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(filePath));

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(SchedaPaziente.this, "Something wrong: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

// close the document
document.close();
Toast.makeText(SchedaPaziente.this, "PDF is created!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

openGeneratedPDF();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
chM.setChecked(true);
```

Or replace CheckBox with ToggleButton.

Comment: chM.setChecked(true) doesen't work. ToggleButton work but it's not the perfect feature because i need a CheckBox

Comment: @FullVisionDalton If it works when you set it from layout then I would suggest doing some stupid check like following: 1. Do everything the same till setChecked(true) inclusive. 2. Then start new thread which will do all other work but inside this thread do some 5s sleep. If it works then it means that some checkbox animation was not finished before you are converting layout to pdf, so in fact checkbox is checked, however it just didn't appear to be checked.

Comment: Unfortunately even with this method the CheckBoc doesen't work.
`chM.setChecked(true);
try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    android.util.Log.d("YourApplicationName", ex.toString());
                }`

Comment: @FullVisionDalton You need to start new thread, not just do sleep, because you are sleeping in UI thread now, so if this is the case with animation then the animation can't proceed because UI thread is blocked.

Comment: I try start a new Thread like this `chM.setChecked(true);
                Thread thread = new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(5000);
                        }
                        catch (InterruptedException e) {
//nothing
                        }
                    }
                };thread.start();` 
First at all i hope i'm doing right and if i'm doing right it doesen't work

Comment: @FullVisionDalton You are starting thread correctly but you need to put all other code there. So leave chM.setChecked(true); outside thread but inside thread (after sleep) put everything else starting from content.draw(page.getCanvas()); I'm not guaranteeing that it will work but if it's the case with animation then it should.

Comment: Doesen't work, if i put all the stuff after sleep the app crash

Comment: Check logs, maybe it crashes because you are trying to display toast in non UI thread. Maybe you could comment out toast creation. Or maybe your openGeneratedPDF(); function is doing something in UI thread.